# How to not repeat methods throughout server app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, architecture

I'm trying to learn good architecture for a node server, but there is something that bother me,
in my attempt to create 3 layered design I come to such folders structure:

```
server/
--|api/v1/vacancies.js
--|config/db/index.js
--|services/vacanciesService.js
--|models/vacanciesData.js
```

and here is some code:

vacancies.js

```
router.get("/:id", () => service.getById());
router.delete("/:id", () => service.deleteById());
router.patch("/:id", () => service.updateById());
router.post("/", () => service.create());
```

vacanciesService.js

```
const getById = () => {};
const create = () => {};
const updateById = () => {};
const deleteById = () => {};

module.exports = {
  get,
  getById,
  create,
  updateById,
  deleteById,
};
```

vacanciesData.js

```
const db = require("../config/db");

...

module.exports = {
      get,
      getById,
      create,
      updateById,
      deleteById,
};
```

basically I'm repeating these 5 methods throughout whole app, but I'm feeling the smell, please help me, what should I do?

Comment: Is any of the code repeated or just the same scaffolding, but different code in each implementation?

Comment: code is different, specific to a layer,  but this scaffolding so ugly

Comment: You can probably put the scaffolding in a base class and then make each implementation a sub-class and then put some of the scaffolding functionality shared in the base class.  We would benefit from seeing 2 or 3 actual implementations to offer more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it if you need the flexibility. The API could evolve independently of the service layer and vice-versa and that's when you will reap the benefits.

If you feel like it's too heavy then perhaps your application is too simple to justify such layering and you could merge responsibilities, such as removing the service layer and merge it with the API layer. Architectures aren't one-size fits all, it's all about striking the right balance for the system your are building.

Simple CRUD apps most likely won't benefit this kind of layering much, but at the same time what starts as a simple CRUD app could evolve into something complex enough that warrants this kind of architecture and then you'd have to have the rigor to refactor.